# Captcha BotDetect: Unexpected token < appears every other page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, ion-auth, botdetect

Using Captcha BotDetect for Codeigniter 3 with ion auth

first load:

- normal output
- no error if submitted

if refreshed:

- captcha is displayed except for reload icon, probably crashed the remaining tasks after the error.
- error will appear if submitted

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" appears in console every other refresh and still display some parts of the captcha on page but gives an error upon submit.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  session_start(): Failed to
>   decode session object. Session has been destroyed
>
> Filename:
>   Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 143

Comment: and what does line 143 say?

Comment: @delboy1978uk session_start();

Comment: ok check the `error_log` for more info and post anything you find